# gcc basic C program doesn't compile: File missing in Ubuntu

Tags: c, node.js, gcc

This has been occurring to me when I tried to compile a basic C program.
Can someone help out?.

I'm having troubles because of this in node-gyp rebuild for npm.

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h:9:0,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/stdint.h:34:10: fatal error: bits/stdint-intn.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/stdint-intn.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Basically, you don't have a complete installation of the relevant headers.  You need to (re)install the relevant package(s).

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete or incompatible gcc/glibc installation? [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=stdint-intn.h&mode=filename&suite=cosmic&arch=any) says you would need `libc6-dev` package for `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdint-intn.h`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run command:

```
locate stdint-intn.h
```

To find out where this file is.

Maybe this file is missing in your OS